# [Close]does Nginx will effect to apache ant?

Tags: java, apache, cordova, ant, nginx

I have the **Apache 2** in my machine and lately I have discovered about **Nginx.**

I just want to know if I replace my **Apache** with **Nginx**, does it will effect with my Ant?

I use Ant for the Phonegap that I've run via terminal for my mobile web development.

And all I've know that Ant is apart of Apache foundation, is right?

I just ask because I want to use Nginx without effecting the Ant.

Thanks for advance!.

Answer (score 0):

No, there will be no impact on *ant* if you uninstall the *Apache web server* and install *nginx*, unless you have a *ant* task calling *the Apache web server* (but then it's easy to check in your xml file and it's probably easy to reconfigure).

The Apache fundation does many things that are not at all related to the Apache web server.

For example *ant*.

Or *Cordova*.

Comment: so, that mean I still can use and develop my phonegap app without any worries if I use Nginx, right?